# PHP find half-unknown string in file

Tags: php

I am writing some code, but I got stuck at the point where I wanted to implement a language system apart from the database (maybe integrating it later).
At the moment I have these lines of code in my language class:

```
final public function findTexts()
{
    global $engine;
    $file = file_get_contents('./styles/'.$engine->getStyle().''.$engine->getPage());
    if(strpos($file, '%%'))
    {
        echo "String found";
    }
}
```

Let me show you my other function:

```
final public function getText($text)
{
    global $engine, $LANG;
    $text = str_ireplace($text, $LANG[substr($text, 2, -2)], $text);
    echo $text;
}
```

What I wanted to do, is check a file (which is inside a styles folder) for a string (for example %%Hi%%). Inside my language file I says Hi == Hello, so when I do the getText function it will say 'Hello'. But, I want to make it simple so you only have to type %%Hi%% inside your file, and the language class will automatically check all strings containing %% at the beginning, and %% at the end, and will replace the string inside the %% and %% with the given string inside the language file.

Hope that is enough info...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using regular expressions and [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). See my example below:

```
<?php
final public function findTexts()
{
    global $engine;
    $file = file_get_contents('./styles/'.$engine->getStyle().''.$engine->getPage());
    $language = $this;
    $file = preg_replace_callback('/(%%([^%]+)%%)/',function($matches) use ($language){
        $word = $matches[2];
        return $language->getText($word);
    },$file);
}
```

This method can become very slow if you have a lot of files or a lot of replacements. It's great if you are doing a very small personal website. If you're doing something a bit bigger, I highly recommend caching the result so you don't have to recompute it for every request and file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it ain't working. Could you explain me a little bit more about preg_replace_callback. Because I do not understand the usage of function($matches) and use ($engine) though.

Comment: I presume the method getText is part of the $engine variable. The function($matches) use ($engine) is an anonymous function that imports the variable $engine into its variable scope so it can use it. You could also use global $engine inside of the function definition too since $engine is a global variable.

Comment: Accually, the getText is in the $language variable, the same as findTexts(). I get the point now, but $this neither $language doesn't work, can you tell me what could work?

Comment: See my changes to the anonymous function. You could of very easily of [googled](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php+use+$this+in+anonmous+function&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=php+use+$this+in+anonymous+function&rls=en&spell=1) this.